# fill style in javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have  to fill an image with r g b a component. It is working with function `something.fillStyle = " rgba ("+r+","+g+","+b+","+a+")";` but i want to use `something.fillStyle = value` where `value` is the color value in hex of the form `alpha r g b`. When `value` is `#ffff00` (yellow) it is fine but when I use a value with alpha (`#ffffff00`) it is always black. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, see http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#numerical. Hex color values don't allow setting the "alpha" value, that's only possible with `rgba` and `hsla`.

Answer (score 0):

It **is** possible, if you convert the hex to rgb and then add your alpha value. Also, you can set the globalAlpha which will apply even if the rest of the colors in the function are using hex colors.

```
if (myAlpha) {
    ctx.globalAlpha = myAlpha;
}
```

take a look at the hextorbg function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb).